# Find entities containing a sublist of elements from an embedded array in MongoDB with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB entity that has a list of tags:

```
@Document
@TypeAlias("project")
data class Project(@Id var id: String?,
                   val name: String,
                   val tags: MutableList<Tag>)
```

I would like to look for Project's containing a subset of the tags.

For example given these proyects:

```
projectService.save(Project(null, "someProject11",  
    mutableListOf(Tag("area","IT"), Tag("department","Architecture"))))

projectService.save(Project(null, "someProject12", 
    mutableListOf(Tag("area","IT"), Tag("department","HR"))))
```

If I define my repository as follows:

```
interface ProjectRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Project, String> {
    fun findByTags(tags : List<Tag>): Flux<Project>
}
```

Looking for a subset doesn't work, e.g: projects with `Tag("area","IT")` should return two results but actually returns 0. The underlying mongo query is:

```
{"find": "project", "filter": {"tags": [{"key": "area", "value": "IT"}]}
```

It only works passing the complete content of the list `listOf(Tag("area","IT"), Tag("department","Architecture"))`:

```
{"find": "project", "filter": {"tags": [{"key": "area", "value": "IT"},{"key": "department", "value": "Architecture"}]}
```

How can I query for entities containing a subset of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `Criteria` and the `$elemMatch` operator:

```
interface CustomProjectRepository {
    fun findByTags(tags: List<Tag>): Flux<Project>
}

class CustomProjectRepositoryImpl(private val mongoTemplate: ReactiveMongoTemplate) : CustomProjectRepository {
    override fun findByTags(tags: List<Tag>): Flux<Project> {
        val query = Query()
        val criterias = mutableListOf<Criteria>()
        tags.forEach {
            criterias.add(Criteria.where("tags").elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").`is`(it.key).and("value").`is`(it.value)))
        }
        query.addCriteria(Criteria().andOperator(* criterias.toTypedArray()))
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Project::class.java)
    }
}

interface ProjectRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Project, String>, CustomProjectRepository {

    fun findByClientIdAndId(clientId: String, id: String): Mono<Project>
    fun findByClientId(clientId: String): Flux<Project>
}
```